# Curves not showing in Object Mode

Tags: bezier-curves

[image][image]

For some reason when I add a curve it doesn't show when in object mode only edit mode. Could someone clarify this?

Comment: It should show up. It would be hard to see it if the background was black. Could you upload the file?

Comment: 1.Viewport Shading: rendered; 2.Object Properties panel > Display: Only Render. These two modes hide the curve object visibility.

Comment: Use this link to upload a file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Here's the blender file (2.8) [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5839" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5839/)

Comment: Also just uploaded the pics

Comment: When I open your file, I can see the curve in object mode, so - probably - it's a graphic card or monitor resolution issue. Do you have the same problem in 2.79 version? If you give to the curve some extrude value in the properties panel is it still invisible?

Comment: If the curve has some extrude value then it shows otherwise it doesn't. Is this why?

Comment: It appears that there have been other cases of this happening. This could be a bug. When is the next stable release of Blender due?

Comment: I thought I had a bug or something. Try turning up the bevel depth on the object data properties tab @sma11world

Answer (score 2):

I just found that problem and I solved it. In the 2.8 version it's not broken, just go to the object properties> object display and select the nurbs path and change the display texture to bounds.

You will now see that it's visible even without edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when adding anything from Extra Curves Object. The issue was caused because my configuration was with the option "enter in edit mode" enabled. In the case of the extra curves, if this option is enabled, the curves don't show.